# simulate leach using inet 3.2.4 and omnet++4.6

Tags: inet

I want to simulate LEACH protocol in wsn, I use inet 3.2.4 and omnet++ 4.6 both working fine. I execute tutorials with inet. I use StandrdHost module to build my wsn,how a node is declared as a cluster head and other surrounding nodes know it, and how packet is forwarded through a specific nodes, i.e. where i should write my routing protocol and then configure in the network.